# Can't find the symbol on line 10?

Tags: java, symbols

```
 //Question
            String readyOne = console.readLine("Are you ready for your first question?  ");
            console.printf(readyOne);
            if (readyOne.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            String questionOne = console.readLine("1 + 1 =  ");
            console.printf(questionOne); }

          //Answer
          if (questionOne.equals("2") || 
              questionOne.equalsIgnoreCase("two")) {
              console.printf("Well done");
          }
```

error:

```
symbol:   variable questionOne
location: class oldjack
oldjack.java:36: error: cannot find symbol 
          questionOne.equalsIgnoreCase("two")) {
          ^
symbol:   variable questionOne
location: class oldjack
2 errors
```

Comment: Which one is line 10 or 11?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error you are getting into the question?

Comment: what symbol? and where exactly?

Comment: Added the actual error

Comment: sweet guys, answered it perfectly:)

Answer (score 7):

This is a typical example why code formation matters:

```
String readyOne = console.readLine("Are you ready for your first question?  ");
console.printf(readyOne);
if (readyOne.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    String questionOne = console.readLine("1 + 1 =  ");
    console.printf(questionOne);
} // lifeness of questionOne ends here

// Answer
if (questionOne.equals("2") || questionOne.equalsIgnoreCase("two")) {
    console.printf("Well done");
}
```

The variable `questionOne` is only alive and visible within the first `if`-block

To fix this problem, one can move the 2nd `if` into the first `if`:

```
String readyOne = console.readLine("Are you ready for your first question?  ");
console.printf(readyOne);
if (readyOne.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    String questionOne = console.readLine("1 + 1 =  ");
    console.printf(questionOne);
    // Answer
    if (questionOne.equals("2") || questionOne.equalsIgnoreCase("two")) {
        console.printf("Well done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, variable *scope* works on a block level. Any block you see surrounded in `{ ... }` braces has its own scope.

Variable scope means that variables declared in deeper (or "sibling") scopes are not visible in other scopes.

You have something like

```
if (condition) {
    String x = "";
}

if (x.equals("2")) {
  ...
}
```

The problem with this code is that `x` (in your case, `questionOne`) is only declared if we go inside the `if` block. Imagine if the condition (`readyOne.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")` in your case) is not met, then `questionOne` will not be declared.

What you will want is to declare `questionOne` outside of the `if` block, and set it to a different value if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

`questionOne` is local to the block it is declared in. You need to declare it outside that block.

```
String questionOne;
if (readyOne.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    questionOne = console.readLine("1 + 1 =  ");
    console.printf(questionOne);
} else {
    questionOne = ...   // Needs to be assigned here too.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `questionOne` is declared *inside a block* - the block that comes after the `if` condition.

Therefore it is only available inside that block. Once you are outside that block (the next `if` is outside) then it doesn't exist anymore.

You need to move the second `if` inside the block where the `questionOne` is declared. It's also illogical for it to be outside it, as outside of that `if` you don't know if the answer was `yes` or `no` or what.